# Saving filenames of a list of imported files into a column of a data frame

Tags: r

I'm reading and combining a large group of csv tables into R but before merging them all I'll like to create a column with the name of the file where those specific set of rows belong.

Here is an example of the code I wrote to read the list of files:

```
archivos <- list.files("proyecciones", full.names = T)
#proyecciones is the folder where all the csv files are located.
tbl <- lapply(archivos, read.table, sep="", head = T) %>% bind_rows()
```

As you can see I already have the names of the files in "archivos" but still haven't been able to figure it out how to put it into the lapply command.

Thanks!

Comment: just nice someone asked this recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100250/add-file-name-to-appended-dataset-for-each-file-in-r the comments there should be useful

Comment: Could you please tell me whether the code in the solution works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use the `.id` in `bind_rows`

```
lapply(archivos, read.table, sep="", header = TRUE) %>%
    set_names(archivos) %>%
    bind_rows(.id = 'grp')
```

---

A more tidyverse syntax would be

```
library(tidyverse)
map(archivos, read.table, sep='', header = TRUE) %>%
     setnames(archivos) %>%
     bind_rows(.id = 'grp')
```

Comment: It worked well, but not completely. Now that I have the "grp" column with the index number of the "archivos" file. How can change that number into the name of that specific file?

Comment: @Guillermo.D  I got it why you are getting that.  Because the list names are empty.  Just use `set_names` (updated the code)