# Read multiple files, create a data frame and add a new column containing the name of each file in R

Tags: read.table, multiple-file-upload

I am new using dplyr package and I have been trying to read multiple files in R and then create a data frame by binding all the rows, but including the name of each file as a new column. This new column is the corresponding date which is not included in the data.

My list of files (for example):
01012019.aps
02012019.aps

I would like to have my final dataframe like this:

```
x y file      date
1 4 01012019  01-01-2019
2 5 01012019  01-01-2019
3 6 02012019  02-01-2019
4 7 02012019  02-01-2019
```

I've been trying this:

```
path_aps<- "C:/Users/.../.../APS"

files_aps <- list.files(path_aps, pattern = "*.aps")

data_aps <- files_aps %>%
  map(~ read.table(file.path(path_aps, .), sep = "\t")) %>%
  map(~ mutate(filename = files_aps, .))%>%
  reduce(gtools::smartbind)
```

But I am getting this error:

> Error: Column `filename` must be length 288 (the number of rows) or one, not 61

I understand that the list of files in `files_aps` has 61 elements as this is the number of files that I have in my directory and 288 is the number of rows of each .aps file; however, I haven't been able to make it work to the extend of each .aps file. I've been reading multiple answers to similar questions but still I am not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it with the help of this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44463022/12404212) and I've got this:

`data_aps <- list.files(path_aps, pattern = "*.aps", full.names = TRUE) %>%
  map_df(function(x) read.table(x, sep = "\t") %>%
  mutate(filename=gsub(".aps","", basename(x))))`